# What is a good way create a Javascript array-like object?

Tags: javascript

The reason why I want to have something like this is to be able to add custom methods/props to certain arrays only. I came up with this little object that works well but I'm wondering if you guys have better way.

```
(function (scope) {
    var target = scope || window;
    target.Hurray = function() { 
        this.length = 0;
        this.count = 0;
        var _arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        this.reset = function() {
            for (var prop in this) {
                if (!isNaN(prop)) {
                    this[prop] = undefined;
                    try {
                        delete this[prop];
                    } catch(e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var x = 0; x < _arr.length; x++) {
                this[x] = _arr[x];
            }
            this.length = _arr.length;
            this.count = this.length;
        };
        this.reset();
        this.toArray = function() {
            return _arr;
        };
        this.concat = function() {
            _arr.concat.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.indexOf = function() {
            var index = _arr.indexOf.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return index;
        };
        this.join = function() {
            var rtn = _arr.join.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return rtn;
        };
        this.lastIndexOf = function() {
            var index = _arr.reverse().indexOf.apply(_arr, arguments).reverse();
            return index;
        };
        this.pop = function() {
            var elem = _arr.pop.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return elem;
        };
        this.push = function() {
            var elem = _arr.push.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return elem;
        };
        this.reverse = function() {
            _arr.reverse.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.shift = function() {
            var elem = _arr.shift.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return elem;
        };
        this.slice = function() {
            return _arr.slice.apply(_arr, arguments);
        };
        this.sort = function() {
            _arr.sort.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.splice = function() {
            _arr.splice.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.toString = function() {
            return _arr.toString.apply(_arr, arguments);
        };
        this.unshift = function() {
            _arr.concat.apply(_arr, arguments);
            this.reset();
            return this.length;
        };
        this.valueOf = function() {
            return _arr.concat.apply(_arr, arguments);
        };
        this.add = function() {
            return this.push.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        this.removeAt = function(index) {
            return this.splice(index, 1);
        };
        this.find = function(value, caseInsensitive) {
            var rtn = new Hurray();
            if (!caseInsensitive) {
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    var currval = this[x];
                    if (currval == value)
                        rtn.push(currval);
                }
            } else {
                value = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    var currval = this[x].toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (currval == value)
                        rtn.push(currval);
                }
            }
        };
        this.findByProperty = function(key, value, caseInsensitive) {
            var rtn = new Hurray();
            if (!caseInsensitive) {
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    var currval = this[x][key];
                    if (currval == value)
                        rtn.push(currval);
                }
            } else {
                value = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    var currval = this[x][key].toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (currval == value)
                        rtn.push(currval);
                }
            }
        };
        this.replace = function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.splice(1, 1, 0); // Add 1 as the delete parameter
            return this.splice.apply(this, args);
        };
        this.insert = function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.splice(1, 0, 0); // Add 0 as the delete parameter
            return this.splice.apply(this, args);
        };
        this.addRange = function() {
            return this.concat.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        this.insertRange = function() {
            var arrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var index = arrays.splice(0, 1);
            for (var x = 0; x < arrays.length; x++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < arrays[x].length; k++) {
                    _arr.splice(index++, 0, arrays[x][k]);
                }
            }
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.getRange = function() {
            return this.concat.slice(this, arguments);
        };
        this.remove = function(value, onlyFirstFind) {
            var index = _arr.indexOf(value);
            if (index == -1) return this;
            _arr.splice(index, 1);
            index = _arr.indexOf(value);
            if (!onlyFirstFind) {
                while (index != -1) {
                    _arr.splice(index, 1);
                    index = _arr.indexOf(value);
                }
            }
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.clear = function() {
            _arr = [];
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.contains = function(value, caseInsensitive) {
            if (!caseInsensitive) {
                return this.indexOf(value) != -1;
            } else {
                var value = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    if (this[x].toString().toLowerCase() == value) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        this.each = function(callback) {
            for (var x = 0; x < _arr.length; x++) {
                var newVal = callback.apply(this, [_arr[x]]);
                if (newVal)
                    _arr[x] = newVal;
            }
            this.reset();
            return this;
        };
        this.toHurray = function() {
            return this;
        };


    };
    Array.prototype.toHurray = function () {
        return new Hurray().concat(this);
    };
})();  //scope goes here!
```

Comment: What's wrong with using regular arrays?  How many do you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need the magic `.length` property, then how about making a constructor function whose prototype is an object that inherits from `Array.prototype`?

```
function Hurray() {}

Hurray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
```

---

```
var h = new Hurray;
h.push('a','b','c');

alert(h.length); // 3

var last = h.pop();

alert(last); // 'c'
alert(h.length); // 2
```

And add your custom methods to <s>`Array.prototype`</s> `Hurray.prototype` as you need. *(Thanks to [Bill Barry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12874/bill-barry) for spotting my mistake!)*

The way you're doing it right now, you're not taking any advantage of inheritance, but instead are creating a bunch of duplicate functions every time a new object is created.

---

If you don't want the original Array methods, you could still use prototypal inheritance for your methods, and use the `Array.prototype` methods under the hood.

```
var _arr_proto = Array.prototype;

function Hurray() {}
Hurray.prototype.length = 0;

Hurray.prototype.add = function() {
    _arr_proto.push.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};
Hurray.prototype.removeFromEnd = function() {
    _arr_proto.pop.apply(this, arguments);
    return this
};
```

Comment: just one small nit, don't modify `Array.prototype`, modify `Hurray.prototype`.

Comment: @BillBarry: Ah, I didn't see it at first, but you're talking about my sentence... *"...add your custom methods to `Array.prototype` as you need"*, and you're absolutely correct. That was a flub... should have said `Hurray.prototype`. Thanks for spotting it!